# SQL Server - WHERE clause with CASE

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetVendor_RMA_CreditMemo
    (@HasCreditMemoNo INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        (SELECT
             CreditMemoNumber,
             CASE WHEN CreditMemoNumber != '' 
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE 0 
             END AS HasCreditMemoNo   
         FROM
             XYZ) as C
    WHERE
        (C.HasCreditMemoNo = @HasCreditMemoNo OR @HasCreditMemoNo = -1)
END
```

`CreditMemoNumber` is a `varchar` column

I want to achieve this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN @HasCreditMemoNo = 0 
      THEN -- select all rows with no value in CreditMemoNumber Column,  
   WHEN @HasCreditMemoNo = 1 
      THEN -- all rows that has some data,   
   WHEN @HasCreditMemoNo = -1 
      THEN -- everything regardless..
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Any sample data and expected result?

Comment: Where are you getting CreditMemoNumber from?  Are you missing a table?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: its working perfectly fine ... but i dont want to use multiple select queries. i was looking for any solution in Where Clause with multiple cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this kind of thing with a CASE.

The correct way to do it is with OR:

```
WHERE (@HasCreditMemoNo = 0 AND {no value in CreditMemoNumber Column})
OR   
     (@HasCreditMemoNo = 1 AND {all rows that has some data})
OR
     (@HasCreditMemoNo = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?  I'm not sure if it would improve your performance.  You may be better off writing an `if else if else` statement and three separate select statements with an index on the CreditMemoNumber column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetVendor_RMA_CreditMemo(@HasCreditMemoNo int)
BEGIN
    select
       CreditMemoNumber,
       case when CreditMemoNumber != '' then 1 else 0 end as HasCreditMemoNo 
    from XYZ
    where
        (@HasCreditMemoNo = 0 and (CreditMemoNumber is null or CreditMemoNumber = ''))
        or (@HasCreditMemoNo = 1 and CreditMemoNumber != '')
        or (@HasCreditMemoNo = -1)
END
```

Comment: `case` statements don't produce boolean expression results. They produce _values_. You have to take the value produced by the `case` statement and compare it to something.

Comment: Thanks!  You are correct.  That's what I get for not testing the code.  The code should work this time, and I added my concern which I should have added previously.